# Python-style string multiplication

Tags: c++, strings, overloading

When people migrate from Python to C++, they're often bothered by the fact that C++ strings don't support multiplication like Python's strings do.

`std::string` does have a constructor that supports creating a string with one character repeated a specified number of times. But, if the pattern to be repeated is more than one character long, C++ provides no convenient solution.

This is an attempt at providing such a solution:

```
#include <string>

std::string operator*(std::string const &in, size_t m) {
    std::string ret;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
        ret += in;
    return ret;
}

std::string operator*(size_t m, std::string const &in) {
    std::string ret;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
        ret += in;
    return ret;
}
```

For example, using these, the typical "print a Christmas tree of asterisks" task could be written something like this:

```
int main() {
    using namespace std::literals;

    std::cout << "Width: ";
    int width;

    std::cin >> width;

    for (int i = 1; i < width; i+=2)
        std::cout << " "s * ((width - i-1)/2) << "*"s * i << "\n";
}
```

[Of course, in this *particular* case, we're only multiplying single-character strings, so the `std::string` ctor would work as well.]

Note that the trailing `s` to make the string literal an `std::string` rather than a `char const *` is necessary--at least one operand of a user-defined operator must be a class or enumeration (or reference to a class or enumeration).

Comment: "they're often bothered" ...Really? I don't think I've ever actually used that feature for anything in production.

Comment: @jpmc26: Most people try to learn the language *before* writing production code.

Comment: I'm not my phone so I can't write a full answer (sorry), but as an optimization, you can do this: https://golang.org/src/strings/strings.go?s=10765:10804#L409 instead of the algorithm being O(N) operations it's O(log N).

Comment: @eric_lagergren, pretty nice idea. Something around binary power, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, it copies bytes in chunks that double in size each iteration. Go's `copy` builtin function won't write past the end of the array, so no extra housekeeping is needed.

Answer (score 7):

**Code duplication:**

There is a code duplication in the overloads of the operator. I believe that the second should call the first with parameters swapped, or vice versa.

**Last feature:**

The last thing I would add, aside from what @Justin mentioned, is some support for `std::basic_string<>`. Although it will introduce abundance of template parameters, the code will be more or less generic.

Do note that in this case reserving might make sense.

Answer (score 5):

You should really put the operators in a namespace. I would recommend not even using operator overloading, and instead making a `repeat(std::string const& str, size_t m)`, but if you want to do the operator overloading, putting it in a namespace makes it easier for a user to opt-in:

```
#include <string>

namespace string_mul {

std::string operator*(std::string const &in, size_t m) {
    std::string ret;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
        ret += in;
    return ret;
}

std::string operator*(size_t m, std::string const &in) {
    std::string ret;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
        ret += in;
    return ret;
}

}
```

---

You could also gain a (very) slight performance benefit by pre-reserving the data for the string:

```
std::string operator*(std::string const &in, size_t m) {
    std::string ret;

    ret.reserve(in.size() * m + 1); // + 1 for null terminator

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
        ret += in;
    return ret;
}
```

---

Putting it together, the code would look like so:

```
#include <string>

namespace string_mul {

std::string operator*(std::string const &in, size_t m) {
    std::string ret;

    ret.reserve(in.size() * m + 1);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
        ret += in;
    return ret;
}

std::string operator*(size_t m, std::string const &in) {
    std::string ret;

    ret.reserve(in.size() * m + 1);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
        ret += in;
    return ret;
}

}

// ...

int main() {
    using namespace std::literals;
    using namespace string_mul;

    std::cout << "Width: ";
    int width;

    std::cin >> width;

    for (int i = 1; i < width; i+=2)
        std::cout << " "s * ((width - i-1)/2) << "*"s * i << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Can I pull the code into my repo? I will add the `std::basic_string<>` stuff on top of it.

Comment: @Olzhas I don't understand your question.  Are you asking If you can put my recommendations in your answer? I really don't think that would be necessary,  especially since you already forward the reader in to my answer

Comment: No, I just want to ask if the code in the post is public licensed, so I could take modified version into my github.

Comment: @Olzhas Whatever I post on SE by default has their specified license (CC BY SA) attached. Usually I'm perfectly fine with anyone doing anything within the bounds of that license